# Errors with closing braces/semicolons

Tags: java, debugging

I've got two compile errors in one of my classes and I don't understand why they're there.

The top error is saying there needs to be another semi-colon and the bottom one says it needs another closing brace.

The bottom error disappears if i put in another curly brace but the top one doesn't.  Any ideas?

(This is probably a case of me being blind/stupid so i apologise in advance :)

```
package com.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class EdgeNodeFactory
{
static boolean[][] edgeMatrix = new boolean[100][100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        edgeMatrix[i][j] = false;
    }
}

static ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
static ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

static int edgeCount = 0;
static int nodeCount = -1;
}
```

[image: errors regarding curly braces]

Comment: PLease post the offending code

Comment: Instead of a screen grab, please post the actual code.

Comment: In future, please cut and paste code as *text* rather than an image. There's no benefit in having an image here.

Comment: Sorry, i just thought you might want to see where the errors are showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried to put code (the `for` loop) directly in your class - it's not in a constructor, a method, or a static/instance initializer. That's not valid. When do you want that code to be executed?

I *suspect* your code should really look like this:

```
public class EdgeNodeFactory
{
    private boolean[][] edgeMatrix = new boolean[100][100];
    private int edgeCount = 0;
    private int nodeCount = -1;
    private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private List<Node> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    public EdgeNodeFactory()
    {
        // You *could* put your for loop here... but the array
        // elements will all be false anyway, as that's the default...

        // If you don't need any code in this constructor, and you
        // don't declare any other constructors, you can remove it
        // entirely - the compiler will create it by default.
    }

    // Other methods here
}
```

Note how I've made all the fields private and non-static... you should almost certainly be creating an *instance* of `EdgeNodeFactory` rather than using static fields, and you should almost always make fields private.

Answer (score 2):

Has been a while since I did any Java, but I believe that for loop should be inside a method or function of some description, rather than the class declaration.

I would imagine you mean that to be in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the for loops are meant to do is initialization of static array field. In this case you should put the code in a static initializer like this:

```
package com.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class EdgeNodeFactory
{
static boolean[][] edgeMatrix = new boolean[100][100];
static {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
      {
          edgeMatrix[i][j] = false;
      }
  }
}

static ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
static ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

static int edgeCount = 0;
static int nodeCount = -1;
}
```

The code inside `static { ... }` at the class level is executed the first time the class is loaded (only once). This means it will be executed before any instances of the class are created and before any other code can access the class.

It remains debatable whether the fields should be static, but if you're sure they should, this is how you should initialize them.